# SQLite datetime gives unreadable 7+ digit month and day

Tags: sqlite, datetime

When I run the following query in my SQLite database, intended to make an unixtime datetime into a readable format:

```
select datetime('1483228802') from mytable limit 1;
```

I get the following result:

```
4056230-49125276-18 12:00:00
```

Clearly something is wrong. The day and month is unreadable, and the year and time is wrong as this python code to convert this unixtime show:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = int("1483228802")
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

>2017-01-01 00:00:02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `'unixepoch'` modifier. Without that the number is interpreted as Julian days.

```
SELECT datetime(1483228802, 'unixepoch');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=83094c556a2287f9473071680b4b3257)

From ["Date And Time Functions"](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> The "unixepoch" modifier (11) (...) causes the DDDDDDDDDD to be interpreted not as a Julian day number as it normally would be, but as Unix Time (...)